# Excel 2013: Cannot open PivotTable source file error after renaming the file/workbook

Tags: excel

I have a pivot table on tab PTable.  The data for this pivot table is in the same workbook (PTWork) on tab PriList.  Everything works fine.
If I change the name of the workbook to PTWorkRen, and try to refresh the pivot table, I get

```
Cannot open PivotTable source file '[PTWork]PriList'.
```

Is there any way to tell Excel to just use the current workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the data source for the pivot table has the workbooks filename in the reference. I could change it by going to change PivotTable Tools on the ribbon and then clicking Analyze > Change Data Source. There I just erased the filename.